# Not getting proper daily high and low on Historical bars

Tags: pine-script

I am using the following code to calculate Daily High and Low`dayHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off) dayLow = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)`

I am using on the 15 mins chart. In the live market it shows me the correct update values on the 15 minutes as the chart progresses, but when I try checking the H/L every bar in the history(i.e before today) it shows be the Daily High and Low which formed end of day but not the actual H/L which happened on that 15 min bar.I tried using barmerge.lookahead_on too, but the results were same

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem

```
// Keep track of current day's high.
```

var dayHigh = 0.0
dayHigh := change(dayofweek) ? high : max(high, dayHigh)